# Problema con promesa al recoger valores que devuelve

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Dentro de una función, necesito llamar a otra en la que he utilizado promesas y me devuelve una serie de datos que necesito para seguir.

Mi problema es que no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o no, porque **no lanza error pero me devuelve un objeto vacío. Si lo muestro con console.log me devuelve: Object Promise**

El código es:

```
getData: function (results) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      Common.getProvider(results).then(function(provider) {

          provider.getData().then(function (providerData) {
              var name = providerData.name;
              var type = providerData.type;
              var lang = providerData.language;

              var data = [];
              data.push(name);
              data.push(type);
              data.push(lang);

              resolve(data);
            },
            function (error) {
              reject(error);
              console.log("Error 1", error);
            }
          );
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log("Error 2", error);
          reject(error);
        })
      .catch(
        function (error) {
          console.log("Error catch", error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });

},
```

Y en la siguiente función necesito trabajar con esos datos (data):

```
extractData: function(results) {

var resultsPDF = [];
var resultsImg = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  if (results[i].fileMimeType == "application/pdf") {
    resultsPDF.push(results[i]);
  }
  else {
    resultsImg.push(results[i]);
  }
}

if (resultsPDF.length > 0) {

  var datosQnecesito = Controller.getData(resultsPDF);
  console.log("DATOS = "+ datosQnecesito); //Devuelve Object Promise
  console.log(JSON.stringify(prov)); //Devuelve {}

  //A partir de aquí necesitaré trabajar con esos datos que recibo
  //...
  }
}
```

**¿Cómo recojo los datos que devuelve la promesa correctamente para posteriormente poder trabajar con ellos?**

Si existe alguna manera alternativa de hacerlo también me puede servir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde ya sabemos que  `getData` devuelve una promesa, por lo cual el llamado a

```
var datosQnecesito = Controller.getData(resultsPDF);
```

No contiene los datos. Contiene una promesa, y tú quieres el valor que saldrá cuando la promesa se resuelva. Por lo tanto debiera ser:

```
Controller.getData(resultsPDF)
 .then(function(datosQnecesito) {
     console.log("DATOS = ", datosQnecesito); 
     //A partir de aquí necesitaré trabajar con esos datos que recibo
     //...
 });
```

No tengo idea de qué será `prov` así que no lo puse en el código de ejemplo.

---

Dicho lo anterior, hay dos cosas que yo mejoraría y me siento obligado a comentártelas:

**Primero**, te diría que tu función `getData` está usando `then(success,fail)` [que es un tipo de antipatrón](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern), pues desaprovecha  el comportamiento nativo de las promesas usándolas como si fueran callbacks.

**Segundo**, para este caso realmente no necesitas usar un constructor de promesa envolviendo todo. Eso también [es otro antipatrón](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern) en tu situación.

Yo reescribiría `getData` como:

```
getData: function (results) {

  return  Common.getProvider(results)
    .then(function (provider) {

        return provider.getData();

    }).then(function (providerData) {
      var name = providerData.name;
      var type = providerData.type;
      var lang = providerData.language;
      var data = [];

      data.push(name);
      data.push(type);
      data.push(lang);

      return data;

    });
},
```

`Common.getProvider` es de por sí una promesa. Puedes devolverla tal cual.

Ahora bien, si reescribes el código como te estoy mostrando, verás que no estoy capturando un posible error. Otra gracia de las promesas es que cualquier error intermedio se propagará hasta el primer `catch` (o bien tirará un error  `Unhandled Rejection`). Eso significa que **no necesitas** poner un `catch` en cada promesa, pues eso sería igual de ineficiente que el antiguo método de los callbacks. Deja que las promesas trabajen por ti.

Basta con poner un solo catch en la función que llama a la promesa:

```
Controller.getData(resultsPDF)
 .then(function(datosQnecesito) {
     console.log("DATOS = ", datosQnecesito); 
     //A partir de aquí necesitaré trabajar con esos datos que recibo
     //...
 }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
 });
```

Y ese atrapará cualquier error que se haya presentado en `getData`. Dentro de `getData` tú no tienes por qué usar `throw`. Eso haría de las promesas -de nuevo- sólo una manera distinta de escribir con callbacks. Como escribe Petka Antonov: [Promise returning functions should never throw](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html).

Answer (score 2):

Lo que me parece que no entiendes es el concepto de "promesa". Las promesas son elementos que se utilizan para ejecutar código de forma asíncrona, es decir, código cuyo resultado no se va a obtener en el momento.

No puedes invocar una promesa y utilizar el resultado de ésta en la instrucción siguiente. Lo que haces con las promesas es pasarles una función con el código que quieres que ejecute con el resultado de ésta, en el momento en el que se obtenga.

En tu caso vendría a ser algo así:

```
var promesa = Controller.getData(resultsPDF);
promesa.then(function(datosQnecesito) {
  console.log('DATOS = ' + datosQnecesito);
});
```